# How to get the output parameter value from a stored procedure that already returns a data set?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am using a stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC to return a data set AND several output parameters. I have the data set working great, and I am able to manipulate the data set into a organized table. The problem is with my output parameters. I have the direction set to output, and I have them seemingly correct. How can I get the value of these few output parameters without jeopardizing my data set?

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(SqlViewModel sT)
    {

        var rMaxBalPoint = new SqlParameter("@MaxBalPoint", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        rMaxBalPoint.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
        var rMinBalPoint = new SqlParameter("@MinBalPoint", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        rMinBalPoint.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
        var rIntBalPoint = new SqlParameter("@IntBalPoint", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        rIntBalPoint.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
        var rMaxEER = new SqlParameter("@MaxEER", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        rMaxEER.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
        var rMinEER = new SqlParameter("@MinEER", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        rMinEER.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
        var rIntEER = new SqlParameter("@IntEER", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        rIntEER.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
        var rCooling = new SqlParameter("@Cooling", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        rCooling.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
        var rEnergy = new SqlParameter("@Energy", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        rEnergy.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
        var rSql = new SqlParameter("@Sql", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        rSql.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

        var sql = db.Database.SqlQuery<Get_Sql_Result>("Get_Sql @Type, @Q_HA, @Q_HB, @Q_LF, @Q_LB, @ESS_HA, @ESS_HB, @ESS_LF, @ESS_LB, @CD, @MaxBalPoint, @MinBalPoint, @IntBalPoint, @MaxEER, @MinEER, @IntEER, @Cooling, @Energy, @Sql, @CDHS, @Q_I, @ESS_I",

            new SqlParameter("@Type", sT.type),
            new SqlParameter("@Q_HA", sT.Q_HA),
            new SqlParameter("@Q_HB", sT.Q_HB),
            new SqlParameter("@Q_LF", sT.Q_LF),
            new SqlParameter("@Q_LB", sT.Q_LB),
            new SqlParameter("@ESS_HA", sT.ESS_HA),
            new SqlParameter("@ESS_HB", sT.ESS_HB),
            new SqlParameter("@ESS_LF", sT.ESS_LF),
            new SqlParameter("@ESS_LB", sT.ESS_LB),
            new SqlParameter("@CD", sT.cd),
            rMaxBalPoint,
            rMinBalPoint,
            rIntBalPoint,
            rMaxEER,
            rMinEER,
            rIntEER,
            rCooling,
            rEnergy,
            rSql,
            new SqlParameter("@CDHS", sT.cdhs),
            new SqlParameter("@Q_I", sT.Q_I),
            new SqlParameter("@ESS_I", sT.ESS_I));         

        SqlPartialViewModel obj = new SqlPartialViewModel();
        obj.SqlData = sql;

       return View("Example",obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter collection will contain the output values of your parameters.

I think you're getting stuck here because the parameter collection isn't persisted anywhere; you're just declaring an ad-hoc collection. If you predeclare your parameters collection, you should be able to get the values out of it perfectly happily.

Comment: When I set a breakpoint on the code and check the values on each output parameter, they appear to be null.